# If $\phi\circ f$ and $f$ is analytic, then $\phi$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

A question from a past qualifying exam at my university reads:

Let $f$ be a nonconstant analytic function on the unit disk $D$ and
let $U = f(D)$. Show that if $\phi$ is a function on $U$ (not necessarily even
continuous) and $\phi \circ f$ is analytic on $D$, then $\phi$ is analytic on $U$.

My approach so far is as follows. Because differentiable functions are continuous, then $\phi\circ f$ is  continuous. One can go on to show that $\phi$ must be continuous on $U$. I now want to use Morea's theorem to show that $\phi$ is analytic, i.e. show that $\int_{\partial T}\phi(z)dz=0$ for any triangle $T\subset U$. For $z\in U$, $\phi(z)=\phi(f(w))$ where $f(w)=z$. So I want to rewrite the previous integral in terms of $\phi(f(w))$ and apply Cauchy's theorem to conclude the integral vanishes. However, I don't know how to control the preimage of $T$ under $f$.  Will it even be connected? If I can show that $f^{-1}(T)$ is a domain with peicewise-smooth boundary, then I should be down. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $u_0=f(z_0)$ and $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ ($u_0$ is a regular value) then $f$ has an analytic local inverse $\psi$ between respective neighborhoods. Now, write $\phi(u)=(\phi\circ f) \circ \psi(u)$ for $u$ close to $u_0$ and conclude in this case. You will have to treat the critical values of $f$ aside.

Hint for the critical case $f'(z_0)=0$: Note that as $f$ is non-constant and analytic it is an open mapping. Use this to see that $\phi$ must be continuous at $u_0=f(z_0)$. Finally deduce that $\phi$ is analytic at
$u_0$.

Comment: Does this work for the critical values case? $u_0=f(z_0)$ and $f'(z_0)=0$. Then $e^{f'(z_0)}=1$, so there exists a local inverse $\phi$ for $e^f$ for the respective neighborhoods, i.e. $e^{f}\circ\psi(u)=e^{f\circ\psi(u)}=u$. 
Now for an appropriate chosen branch of the logarithm, we have  $\phi\circ \ln\circ e^{f\circ\psi(u)}=(\phi\circ f) \circ \psi(u)=\phi\circ (f \circ \psi)(u)=\phi(u)$ is analytic in some neighborhood of $u_0$. The results follows.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Taking exponential does not assure a local inverse.

Comment: I've been thinking about the problem a little more, and I feel like it may not be true. Take $\phi(z)=\log(z)=\ln|z|+iArg(z)$. $\phi$ is a well defined function (not continuous) on the complex plane and will be an inverse for $e^z$. Also, $e^{z}$ is analytic on the unit disk. If we assume that the result is true, then because $\phi\circ e^z=z$, then we can conclude that $\phi$ is differentiable on the unit disk, which it is not. Am I missing something?

Comment: I had similar thoughts at some point. In your case, the image $U$ of the unit disk is some domain containing 1 but omitting 0 and the negative axis (if you take the cut to be the negative axis). So your $\phi$ is in fact analytic on $U$. If instead you take $f(z)=\exp(4z)$ then the image crosses the negative axis but $\phi\circ f$ changes the value by $2\pi i$ when crossing, so $\phi\circ f$ was not analytic in the first place. It is quite subtle this problem.  You may try to follow my second hint to show that $\phi$ in fact must be continuous. That $f$ is an open mapping is essential.

Comment: Does this work? To show $\phi$ is continuous at $u_0$ where $f(z_0)=u_0$ and $f'(z_0)=0$ proceed as follows. Let $V\subset \phi(U)$ be open, then $(\phi\circ f)^{-1}(V)=W$ is open and $\phi^{-1}(V)=f(W)$. However, $f$ is an open mapping, so $f(W)$ is open, hence  $\phi^{-1}(V)$ is open and we can conclude that $\phi$ is continuous. We can conclude that the points $u_0$ in $U$ where $f(z_0)=u_0$ and $f'(u_0)=0$ must be isolated, because otherwise $f'$ would have an accumulation point of zeros, which implies that $f'$ is identically zero, which implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: So, $\phi$ will have an isolated singularity at $u_0$. But I have shown that $\phi$ is continuous, so it will achieve a maximum in some closed neighborhood of $u_0$, so the singularity is removable and hence $\phi$ is analytic at $u_0$.

Comment: @MEG Very nice proof! I had in mind using sequences but the way you use the open mapping property is even better. You might just add that $\phi(U)$ is open because it equals $\phi\circ f (D)$ (which is open).

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help!